# The meaning of "not because". Could it have two meanings?

Tags: negation, reasoning

- I don't like him because he is rich.

Could it be interpreted in two ways?

1. I dislike him because he is rich. (I don't like rich people.)
2. The reason why I like him is not the fact that he is rich. (I like
   him because he is a good man.)

I'm sometimes confused when I hear this kind of expression.  Does it depend on the context?  Is there a good way to avoid being ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is ambiguous

Comment: I [wrote about this ambiguity on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/375759/191178).

Comment: in context, usually only one meaning will make sense, but of course there can be a situation where the meaning is still ambiguous. It's easier when spoken, because the inflection would be different.

Comment: Note that a comma before "because" would rule out the second interpretation (in standard English, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Either of the suggested meanings is possible. But in the absence of clarifying context, the meaning

< 1. I dislike him because he is rich. (I don't like rich people.)

is significantly more likely.

Comment: Not sure why you reckon that interpretation is more likely. Maybe you just hang out with a lot of anti-capitalists, and if you hung out with a lot of people who dated rich people, you'd tend towards the opposite ("I like him for his personality not his money").